# JetBrains PhpStorm - comments have a lot of extra space?

Tags: phpstorm, laravel-blade, jetbrains-ide, code-formatting

I just moved from VSCode to PhpStorm. A small annoying thing is that when commenting a section (in a Blade file) PhpStorm adds a lot of (unneeded) space, which I have to go over and manually trim. This is a small thing, but give the amount of comments I'll write using this program, it's better to figure out the issue sooner.

Example:

I have the following code

[image]

I make space for a comment

[image]

Using the Mac shortcut for comment, PhpStorm adds a comment, but to the base line. This means I have to trim the comment each time.

[image]

Desired result: to start to comments below the opening tag on the previous line and placement of the input i.e

[image]

Sidebar:

VS Code does this by default, so I'm not sure if this is a known "feature", not a bug with PhpStorm.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is intentional, the comment shortcuts are - AFAIK - more intended to comment out an existing selection of code, and that way, the comment out section jumps out more. In IntelliJ (which is the same base as PHPStorm), there is a Code Style setting called "Comments at first column". It doesn't seem to control this behaviour, but should do so when reformatting.

Comment: Turn on displaying whitespace symbols -- it will better show if you have the indents done right on that empty new line. When you insert the comment (Block comment on an empty line with no selection) it inserts it in the caret place. Normally (at very least here on my PC), when you hit `Enter` after `</p>` (or alike tag) the IDE will make a new line and indent accordingly. In your case it looks to me that the indent is simply not there (the caret is placed at the first column).

Comment: 1) So check your settings about indent behaviour. Not sure, check the Code Style for HTML and Blade, also check what you have at `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Smart Keys --> Smart Indent` 2) Make a test file where you can reproduce the issue and share the file as well as your Code Style (export as XML format) -- maybe it's something there (specific file content perhaps, or specific block where it does not work right). Need to test and see. In my simple test it works fine here (the right indent and the comment gets inserted at the caret place).

Answer (score 1):

I found the Answer!:

1. Open Settings from the File menu.
2. On the left bar navigate to Editor > Code Style > HTML
3. Select the "Code Generation" tab
4. Uncheck "Line comment at first column" and, if you wish, "Block comment at first column"
5. Clik "Apply"

That's from:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/phpstom-blade-comments

Comment: Yeah that works well - same process for other langs as well i.e. if you are having the issue with PHP, then do the same thing in the PHP settings - thanks for getting back on this post :)